# Find a matrix $X∈V$ such that $U∩W=\mathrm{span}\{X\}.$

Tags: linear-algebra

[image]
Have been trying this problem for $4$ hours still can't figure it out.

Comment: Probably not how you're supposed to do it... but if you think of these as vectors in $\mathbb{R}^3$, then the span of them is a plane.  So, the problem is equivalent to finding the intersection of two planes, which would be a line (or a vector times a parameter).  Get this by taking the cross product for each set of two vectors to get the normal, and then take the cross product of THAT to get the vector you're looking for.

Comment: $au_1+bu_2=cw_1+dw_2$ is.....a system of linear equations!

Answer (score 0):

In three dimensions, Euler....IS_ALIVE's method works, since $$x \times y \in \text{span}(x, y)^\perp = \text{span}(x)^\perp \cap \text{span}(y)^\perp$$
so if we let $U = \text{span}(u_1, u_2)$ and $W = \text{span}(w_1, w_2)$ then
$$x := (u_1 \times u_2) \times (w_1 \times w_2) \in \text{span}(u_1 \times u_2, w_1 \times w_2)^\perp = \text{span}(u_1 \times u_2)^\perp \cap \text{span}(w_1 \times w_2)^\perp \\
= (\text{span}(u_1, u_2)^\perp)^\perp \cap (\text{span}(w_1, w_2)^\perp)^\perp = U \cap W$$
will be a vector in the intersection.

In general dimensions, see the [Zassenhaus algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zassenhaus_algorithm).

Comment: Oops, you are right. I've edited the answer.